# How does Camlp5 (former Camlp4) parse expressions

Tags: ocaml, operator-precedence, recursive-descent, camlp4

As far as I could figure it out by searching in the Internet, it looks like that Camlp5 (former Camlp4) uses a recursive-descent parser, while `ocamlyacc` is an LALR-based parser generator.

In an LALR parser generator, priority and associativity is mapped to shift/reduce conflicts. My question is how a recursive descent-parser such as Camlp5 can deal with declarative operator precedence?

```
 # let expr = Grammar.Entry.create gram "expr";;
 # EXTEND
     expr:
       [ "add" LEFTA
         [ x = expr; "+"; y = expr -> x + y
         | x = expr; "-"; y = expr -> x - y ]
       | "mult" RIGHTA
         [ x = expr; "*"; y = expr -> x * y
         | x = expr; "/"; y = expr -> x / y ]
       | "simple" NONA
         [ x = INT -> int_of_string x
         | "("; e = expr; ")" -> e ] ]
     ;
   END;;
```

How does it deal with left-recursive calls? Does camlp5 (camlp4) use a
table-driven operator precedence approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser

Any insights or links to the internal workings of the Camlp4 parser is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Recursive Descent Parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) is not a table driven parser, like LALR. Decisions, made by a parser are hardcoded in function bodies (each rule is a function). And indeed, `CamlpN` [compiles](http://camlp5.gforge.inria.fr/doc/htmlc/parsers.html#a:Remarks) a grammar definition into a set of mutual recursive functions. The winning point here, is that you don't need to code this functions manually. So, if you change a grammar, you just update a grammar definition and all necessary functions are updated for you. In a regular hand-coded recursive parser you will need to update it yourself, that is very error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the general description, but it looks like you haven't answered my specific question. How does the internal machinary of Camlp4 works with expression grammars that are left-recursive and how does it use LEFA, RIGHTA, NONA and the level information to yield the correct derivation?

Comment: you mean, how in particular the functions are generated?

Comment: Yes, sort of. How does such an specification translate into functions (or other mechanisms). Given left recusive rule, how do we do deal with that?